# In which areas has national autonomy become weaker, and to what extent and in which areas has national autonomy become stronger? (Sovereign States)

Tags: international-relations, international-law, sovereignty, local-autonomy

For more than a decade some academics and political actors have been declaring that the sovereign state is just about dead. The reality is that the states are still here and it doesn’t seem that they will soon disappear. How has the concept of sovereignty changed and to what extent, and in which areas, has national autonomy become weaker, and to what extent and in which areas has national autonomy become stronger?

Comment: Geez, this *really* sounds like a homework question or school essay topic, which isn't normally what we do here. I'm a bit conflicted about answering; I don't want to short-circuit the learning process...

Comment: "some academics and political actors have been declaring that the sovereign state is just about dead"  which academics?  Citation please!

Comment: It's a bit open ended and generic as it is.  Maybe try to narrow it down to something more specific.  Think of it this way:  if it would take more than a page to answer and if the answer would be likely to vary significantly depending on the person doing the answering's opinions, then it's not necessarily a good question for this forum.

I see your question has both those drawbacks and a whiff o homework-iness.

Welcome aboard however.

Comment: A google search ["the+sovereign+state+is+just+about+dead"](https://www.google.com/search?q=the+sovereign+state+is+just+about+dead.&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) probably would help.